# .net core AddSingleton initialization

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to register a singleton class, providing the constructor parameters in Startup.ConfigureServices method.

After several tries, I'm still not able to make the dbContext injection working

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddGrpc();
        services.AddDbContext<EFContext>();

        services.AddSingleton<OPCClient>(x =>
        {
            string endpointURL = "opc.tcp://xxx.yyy.zzz.nnn:12345";
            bool autoAccept = false;
            int stopTimeout = Timeout.Infinite;
            var efContext = x.GetService<EFContext>();

            OPCClient client = new OPCClient(endpointURL, autoAccept, stopTimeout, efContext);
            client.Run();

            return client;

        });
    }


    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        // warmup
        app.ApplicationServices.GetService<OPCClient>();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapGrpcService<OPCService>();

            endpoints.MapGet("/", async context =>
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Communication with gRPC endpoints must be made through a gRPC client. To learn how to create a client, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2086909");
            });
        });
```

When `var efContext = x.GetService<EFContext>();` is executed, I'm getting the exception

```
System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'EFContext' from root provider.'
```

Thanks for any help in injecting the `DbContext` in `OPCClient` class

Comment: I think may be you are trying to resolve / inject Scoped (EFContext) into Singleton (OPCClient) lifetime ?
Take a look at note here 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scoped

Answer (score 5):

It is not a good choice to use a scoped service (the EFContext) inside a singleton.
The DI container creates a new instance of a scoped service for every request, while it creates a singleton only once and this can lead to inconsistent states for your objects. [Documentation here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-2.2#service-lifetimes)

I suggest to change the lifetime of OPCClient to scoped - using services.AddScoped instead of services.AddSingleton. If you cannot do this, pass a reference of IServiceProvider rather than EFContext and resolve that service from the container each time you need to use it:

```
public class OPCClient
{
   private IServicePrivder _serviceProvider;
   public OPCClient (IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   {
     _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
   }

   public void DoSomething() {
       EfContext efContext = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<EfContext>();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I'll have a try! I'm wondering if it could be safe and working injecting the DBContext as a singleton as well. The access to the database is performed just to load some configuration of the application, that will be in common to all the request handled through the gRPC interface. The multithreaded gRPC iface won't have access to the db

Comment: Not use DBContext as singleton you can have some problem  - you'd keep instance of DbContext for a long time and this is not recommended.

Comment: So far I was able to make it working only by making DbContext singleton. Using the reference to IServiceProvider, when I call GetRequiredService I get `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot resolve scoped service 'EFContext' from root provider.'`

Comment: Keep in mind that the DbContext holds the connection to the database. In real cases scenario you have many concurrent requests that will need access to the database and Having the DbContext as a Singleton will cause issues. Is there any particular reason why you need the OPCClient to be a singleton?